# Android BLE difference between BlutoothAdapter.enable(); and call an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

While working with the Blutooth low energy I need to mantain the Bluetooth adapter on.

Recently I've realized that it can be turned on in two different ways.

**First way:**

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().enable();
```

First time I tryed this function I thought this required root or some kind of privileges to work.

Actually I find out none of them is necessary and this function works fine on different devices.

(Samsung S4 Lollipop, Asus Zenpad 8" Marshmellow, Meizu M2 Note Lollipop)

**Second way:**

```
enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE); 
startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, ENABLE_BLUETOOTH_INTENT);
```

By using the intent you can ask the user to turn on the Bluetooth. This one works fine too but you have to listen for intent result. So this require more code and the user can decide to not turn on the bluetooth.

***Do they works fine in every situation? Is there a "better" one? What is the real difference between them?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#enable()):

> Bluetooth should never be enabled without direct user consent. If you want to turn on Bluetooth in order to create a wireless connection, you should use the ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE Intent, which will raise a dialog that requests user permission to turn on Bluetooth. The enable() method is provided only for applications that include a user interface for changing system settings, such as a "power manager" app.

So basically the reason to use `Intent` is just a good UX. I advise to use `Intent` because of that reason.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use BLE in your Application for receiving and transmitting data among device we must require blutooth enabled.

Another point is that device suport BLE or not.

Bluetooth adapter required for doing bluetooth related stuff.

If blutooth is not enabled on device , then ask for user to enable it by using intent and listen for intent. So this more code required.

If user do not turn on bluetooth we can't do BLE related things.

So, require bluetooth adapter and bluetooth on device and enable method provides user interface for changing system settings.